# Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER:

Tags: puppet

Getting error 500

## puppet agent -t

Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
**Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Could not find node statement with name 'default' or 'client.domain.com' on node client.domain.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run**

Puppet.conf content below:

```
[master]
dns_alt_names = master.domain.com,server
certname = master.domain.com

[agent]
server = master.domain.com
ca_server = master.domain.com
certname = client.domain.com
use_cached_catalog = true
```

Comment: On master.domain.com could you do a 'cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp'.

Comment: node 'master.domain.com' {
        package { 'httpd':
                ensure => "installed",
        }
        service { 'httpd':
                ensure => running,
                enable => true
        }
        file    { '/tmp/puppetdir':
                ensure => 'directory',
                owner => 'sysadmin',
                group => 'wheel',
                mode => '0755'
        }
}

Answer (score 3):

Your site.pp file under the manifests folder need to contain either a `node 'client.domain.com'` (as client.domain.com is your certname for the agent) or a `node default`.

For instance:

```
node default {

  file { '/tmp/puppetdir':
    ensure => 'directory',
    owner => 'sysadmin',
    group => 'wheel',
    mode => '0755'
  }

}

node 'client.domain.com' {
  package { 'httpd':
    ensure => "installed",
  }
      
  service { 'httpd':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true
  }

  file { '/tmp/puppetdir':
    ensure => 'directory',
    owner => 'sysadmin',
    group => 'wheel',
    mode => '0755'
  }

}
```